# Google Sites as Wiki--Discussion Option

Tags: google-workspace, google-classic-sites

We are using Google Sites as a wiki. I wonder if there is a way to run a discussion behind the scenes as can be done in Wikispaces. If so, how would you do this with Google Sites. We are all already in as collaborators and are creating our pages. How can we have a behind the scenes discussion about our thoughts about what to put on the pages, what is missing, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google Moderator to catch up on opinions and with Google Group Discussions your able to create topics to discuss on.

The following two references explain how to do it:

- [Google Moderator](http://googledocs.blogspot.nl/2010/08/collect-audience-input-with-google.html)
- [Google Groups Discussion](http://support.google.com/groups/answer/1050653?hl=en)